# TypeError: $(selector) is null

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web page that redirects to another page on click.
On the second page I have this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['tab1'])) { ?>
  <script>$('#home').trigger('click'); </script> 
<?php }?>
```

The `$_POST` comes back ok, only I get this error in the console for the jquery:

In firebug:

```
TypeError: $("#home") is null
```

Or in Chrome:

```
$('#home').trigger('click');
```

If I run this: `alert(document.getElementsByTagName('#home'));`

I get a alert with: `[object HTMLCollection]` as `undefined`

If I view the source I can see my jquery there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

Any ideas on why the jquery fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting it in a document ready to ensure that the DOM is loaded before manipulating it:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['tab1'])) { ?>
    <script>$(function() { $('#home').trigger('click'); } );</script>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 8):

in some setups the $ sign is not an alias for jQuery
(ex. `jQuery.noConflict();` causes that)

see also
[Replace "$"(dollar Sign) with "JQuery"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746352/replace-dollar-sign-with-jquery)

so `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`
is written

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

FIX:

```
   <script>$( window ).load(function() { $('#home').trigger('click'); });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your script in the `ready()` function.
Try something like this:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['tab1'])) { ?>
  <script>$(function(){
           $('#home').trigger('click');
   });</script> 
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuring the document loads first is critical.

```
<script>$(function() { $('#home').trigger('click'); });</script>
```

That's because by the time the script is loaded, it may be possible that `#home` isn't defined yet (because the source code defining it has not yet been downloaded/parsed),
so you should make sure by enclosing it with `$(function() { ... });` or `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the unique solution that worked is this one I've got from [here](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/jquery-documentready-controlid-is-null.html):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
  $j(document).ready(
    function() {
      alert($j("selector")); //object is properly initialized
    }
  );
</script>
```

Use the `jQuery.noConflict();` return variable instead of `$`.