# Rails - Store a cookie in controller and get from Javascript, Jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, session-cookies

Is it possible to store a User's Cookie or Session in Controller and Get the cookie by accessing it from JS or Jquery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Session** values are available on the server.

You can set them like this [in your controller](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base):

```
session[:user_name] = @user.name
```

If you want to access that value later in javascript, you'll probably want to do something like this in a view:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  var userName = '<%= session[:user_name %>';
<% end %>
```

---

**Cookies** are managed by the browser, so accessed differently.

To set one in your controller:

```
cookies[:user_name] = @user.name
```

(You can also specify the path, expiration, etc. for the [cookie using options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).)

It can then be accessed using jQuery:

```
var userName = jQuery.cookie("user_name");
```

Note: you can also [access the cookie using pure javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie) (not jQuery) by parsing `document.cookie`, but it is **much** easier to let jQuery do it for you (if you're already using that library).

Comment: When i do this, I'm getting  $.cookie is not a function. Should i include any Js other than jquery? i'm using jquery.min.1.9.1

Comment: @Srikanth: try using it without the path hash (I've updated that line) in the response.

Comment: Also, depending on what other JS libraries you have loaded, you should replace all your "$" calls with "jQuery".  (Some libraries - "prototype" in particular use the "$" namespace too.  For more info on that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746352/replace-dollar-sign-with-jquery )

Comment: No equal sign before `end` in `<%= javascript_tag do %> ... <%= end %>` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag

Comment: @Kote - I'm using the same.. Thanks :)

Comment: **jquery cookie is deprecated**, use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) instead