# Ajax request failing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am a little stumped as to why my Ajax call is failing, It was working and cannot think of any changes that would have affected it. When i make the call i get an error in firebugs console that points to this in my jquery.js file

```
// Do send the request
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

Firstly what does this mean?

My setup is like so

index.js.erb

```
<% if params[:type] == 'Tynewydd' %>
 $('#newsResults').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tynewyddposts') %>');
<% end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
 <div id="newsResults">
   <div class="hero-unit">
     <h2> Welcome to your admin area</h2>
       <p> xxxxxxxx.</p>
         <p>xxxxxxxxx</p>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Link for ajax request

```
<li><%= link_to 'Tynewydd', posts_path(:type => 'Tynewydd'), :remote => true %></li>
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong here please or offer some debugging suggestions?

Any help appreciated

Edit

Controller

```
def index
@posts = Post.all
@tynewyddpost = Post.tynewydd_posts
@woodsidepost = Post.woodside_posts
@elmspost = Post.elms_posts
@sandpiperpost = Post.sandpiper_posts
@outreachpost = Post.outreach_posts
@companypost = Post.company_posts
@staffpost = Post.staff_posts

respond_to do |format| 
 format.html 
 format.js 

end
```

Ok so i am no longer getting the error, i had an undefined method error for nil class in the called partial, so now in the console I can see the response but the partial that is supposed to render does not display on my page

Thanks

Comment: hey again, can you post your controller action?

Comment: Hi there :), just updated, im using scopes aswell in the post model

Comment: can you remove `<% if params[:type] == 'Tynewydd' %>` from the `.js.erb` file and say if it's working?

Comment: ok, for now don't put it back. Can you also put the `_tynewyddposts.html.erb` file?

Comment: im doing a <% @tynewyddpost.each do |t| %> or do you want the whole file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27672/discussion-between-richlewis-and-zippie)

Comment: @Zippe Hi,I have updated my question with most recent findings

Comment: you didn't add the respond_to do block, did you?

Comment: I have, sorry updated in question

Comment: did you try to remove the `if[:type]` from the `.js.erb`?

Comment: yes tried that aswell, same result

Comment: did you try transfering it to another action?

Comment: found a solution, see answer, but wonder why this has made it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so just in-case anyone else runs into a similar issue changing $ to jQuery has solved the problem, so this

```
<% if params[:type] == 'Tynewydd' %>
 $('#newsResults').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tynewyddposts') %>');
<% end %>
```

was changed to this

```
<% if params[:type] == 'Tynewydd' %>
  jQuery('#newsResults').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tynewyddposts') %>');
<% end %>
```

Comment: are you using any other javascript frameworks/ libraries beside jQuery?

Comment: all jquery and using modernizer.js

Comment: it uses the dollar sign also somewhere? the reason i asked you: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746352/replace-dollar-sign-with-jquery

Comment: ah right it was because I am using jquery.noConflict() as there where conflicts with some plugins I am using..Understand now, thanks for finding that post

Comment: no problem, i heard about that problem i just didn't think of it :) Was trying to find a rails mistake. Good thinking!