# Conflicting Javascript codes. Menu and Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, conflict

I am having some trouble with what looks to be conflicting JavaScript. I'm not the most savvy with it so I was hoping someone here could help me out.

The slider and menu both work on their own in a separate HTML page, but once I place it into the same HTML page it seems that they conflict and neither then work.

I have removed the menu JavaScript code in the head and the slider works so I am pretty sure this is the problem. You can see it [live here](http://zonocreative.co.uk/problem/commercial.html).

Comment: Didn't you looked at your JavaScript console? It throws a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You console show error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js:140
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.themepunch.kenburn.min.js:8
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function commercial.html:32
```

Embed a suitable jQuery library file at the top of all the `scripts`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to include JQuery before you start to use the plugins, so move the line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Before all your JavaScript includes.

Also, you use `jQuery.noConflict()` [and we know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746352) that it "frees" the `$` from being associated with jQuery so change this code:

```
var tpj=jQuery;
   tpj.noConflict();            
   tpj(document).ready(function() {
      if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
         tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;
         tpj('.bannercontainer').kenburn(
         //Etc...
```

And use the `$` sing everywhere.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      if ($.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
         $.fn.css = $.fn.cssOriginal;
         $('.bannercontainer').kenburn(
         //Etc...
```