# How the symbol $ in jquery works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can jquery run a function when ever it sees $ in the script file? $ is not a javascript key character how come when ever $ appear, jquery run its function? do you need to read the script file in some way then eval it? Is it possible to remake this with another symbol?

Comment: '$' is a valid character for a JavaScript function to begin with.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746352/replace-dollar-sign-with-jquery

Comment: How do you make a similar identifier?

Comment: `$` is just a convenient variable name, nothing more. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery JavaScript file has the following line in it:

```
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Meaning that the window-scoped `$` variable will be assigned to the jQuery namespace, in which all the jQuery functions are placed under. This is why you can use `jQuery` in your code as well as `$`.

You could do this easily yourself by the same method and another character symbol, even:

```
window.$$ = jQuery;
```

would mean that jQuery is now assigned to `$$`, etc.

Comment: Oh ok, so would jQuery variable in the code be an object in order to hold all the function?

Comment: jQuery would be the namespace to hold all the functions, yep.

Answer (score 2):

$ symbol may be used as a name of a function. So, this is a valid javascript:

```
var $ = function(selector) {
    console.log("selector");
}
$("body");
```

The other interesting thing in jQuery is that implements the [chaining pattern](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/JavaScript-sequencing-function-calls-parallel-functional-chain-2).