# JavaScript: jQuery(...).extensionName is not a function (not using $)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been searching for the past hour, so I apologize if this is a duplicate I missed.

For some reason the (too long to copy) website I've been working on has recently been giving me JavaScript Console errors like:

`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).sidr is not a function`
`Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).dataTable is not a function`

Notice that I *am* using `jQuery`, **not** `$`.

Any clue what could be causing this?  As I said, my code is WAY too long to copy everything (>1000 lines), plus the issue of removing sensitive/copyright code could be an issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746352/replace-dollar-sign-with-jquery

Comment: "*Recently*" – what changed? If you can't reproduce the whole thing, strip everything out of the plugin/function, and add things back until the error is reproduced. Incidentally, without code (and I suspect you anticipated this, given that you twice explain its absence) all we can do is guess. And guessing does very little good.

Comment: Did you try to replace jQuery by $?

Comment: @SaidKholov I HAVE been using jQuery, NOT $.  You're answering the inverse of my question.

Comment: @DavidThomas good advice, but no work has been done here in 6+ months, so the ticket that got entered TODAY is difficult to trace backwards.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli How it is not answerable?   `What causes this error` seems pretty specific.  Would you like 1000 lines of code to parse through, or is there something else useful I can add to the question?  Genuinely curious, because I really WOULD like to know what's wrong.

Comment: No, you should do some debugging to put together a test case that demonstrates the issue. That means you spend the time pulling out the relevant parts so it's not 1000 lines, but only the few lines that cause the problem. This will probably lead to you figuring out the issue yourself.

Comment: Without your code, how could we possibly know "*what causes this error*"?

Comment: @DavidThomas If someone had *seen* this error before, they might know.  I could obfuscate and share 1000 lines, but I don't expect anyone to read that for fun.  I think Evan's suggestion of getting a jsfiddle working (if possible) is far more useful.

Comment: @Bing if it is a publicly facing website, a URL would likely be the best help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the javascript loading order. Probably you have your code being loaded before jQuery and it's plugins. Like so:

```
<script src="yourcode-app-code.js"></script> 
<script src="jQuery.js"></script> 
<script src="jQuery-plugin-sidr.js"></script>
```

Your code should be last in the list.

Also check the order of plugins. They should be loaded after jQuery.

Does your code use the jQuery(document).ready() ? If not, then your code is being executeed before jQuery or it's plugins are loaded. So you should change the code so it will execute on page load event.

**EDIT**

To debug the order you can add `console.log` right before sidr call in your code and `console.log` in the start of sidr file and check what's executed first. Just to be sure its not a script loading order issue.

Comment: I made that mistake last year.  jQuery is literally the FIRST JavaScript file I load.  The second is jQuery UI.  The third is dataTables.

Answer (score 0):

Well the second error looks like you are trying to use a dataTable, but mistyped it.  The first error appears you are trying to use some jQuery add-in that doesn't exist... Did you forget to put a `<script src="javascripts/sidr/jquery.sidr.min.js"></script>` on your page?

Comment: Negative.  sider.min.js is included.  Here is sidr, for reference: http://www.berriart.com/sidr/

I AM storing it locally.  So maybe I need to update it.  But I believe it was working before.

Comment: Use the net tab in firebug (or chrome) to make sure that jquery.sidr.js is indeed getting requested and the request is not failing.  And make sure jQuery,js is the same (and before jquery.sidr.js).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're loading jQuery twice by accident, some code might then call jQuery.noConflict() which might replace your expected jQuery with an other version.

You might check for jQuery.fn.jquery, maybe even the jQuery version differs to your expected one.