# '$ is undefined' error, but 'jQuery' works

Tags: jquery

I have these lines of code which is the cause of an error message. It seems to me that there is no mistake in the code, but I guess I'm wrong:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");

  $("#hover-table").hover(function() { // THIS IS LINE 164    
    $('#table-wrapper').show();
  }, function() {
    $('#table-wrapper').hide();
  });
});
```

I get this error message in the Chrome console. The `console.log` is printed with no problem.

> (index):164 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>    at HTMLDocument. ((index):164)
>    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
>    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you added jQuery file to your page?

Comment: looks like you have changed your `$` to `jQuery` - might be because of a no conflict? See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746352/replace-dollar-sign-with-jquery

Comment: @Mohammad Without loading jQuery the error would be `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery is not a function`!

Comment: 1) conflicting libraries or 2) some earlier JavaScript breaks, resulting in the following JavaScript to break.

Answer (score 5):

It may that another library using the dollar sign instead of jQuery what will create this conflict so you could replace all the dollars signs `$` with `jQuery` like :

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("ready!");

        jQuery("#hover-table").hover(function() { // THIS IS THE LINE 164---
            jQuery('#table-wrapper').show();
        }, function() {
            jQuery('#table-wrapper').hide();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Or also you could define it for inside-block use like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //You can now use $ as your jQuery object.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with below code, looks like you have changed the $ to jQuery

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   console.log( "ready!" );
   jQuery("#hover-table").hover(function(){ // THIS IS THE LINE 164---
     jQuery('#table-wrapper').show();
   },function(){
     jQuery('#table-wrapper').hide();
  });
 }); 
</script>
```