# How to count Total, Tax using data from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

so im kinda new in codeigniter and web developing in general but is it possible to count Sub Total and Tax, automatically input that value into somekind of input box in codeigniter?

for example :

- i have model that join some column and show the data into a table

table model.php

```
public function getPurchaseOrder()
    {
        $query =$this->db->query('SELECT dkmno, kodeprod,kodebarang_op,qty_op,unit_op,price,catatan FROM order_product JOIN barang_dkm ON order_product.kodebarang_op = barang_dkm.kodebarang');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

table view.php

```
<table class="table table-fixed table-bordered table-hover" style="width:100%;" id="tebal">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">DKM No </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Kode Produksi </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Kode Barang </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Deskripsi </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Jumlah/Quantity </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Unit </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Unit Price </th>
                                        <th scope="col">Sub Total </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php foreach ($dataTabel as $kiki) : ?>
                                        <tr class="table-row">
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["dkmno"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["kodeprod"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["kodebarang_op"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["catatan"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["qty_op"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["unit_op"]; ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $kiki["price"]; ?></td>
                                            <td class="calc"><?php $a=$kiki["qty_op"]*$kiki["price"]; echo $a ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php endforeach;?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

- and i want to count sub total from the table above and show the answer in a textbox or inputbox
- subtotal, discount, and tax code if you want to know

```
<div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-sm" id="kontol">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <label for="SubTotal" class="control-label">Sub Total : </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-9">
                                    <input type="number" id="subTotal" name="SubTotal" value="" style="text-align: right;" class="form-control" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="Discount" class="label-control" id="Discount">Discount : </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="number" name="Discount" class="form-control" id="inputDiscount" value="" min="0" max="100" onchange="calculatedSubTotal()"><span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="number" name="SubTotalDiscount" value="" style="text-align: right;"  class="form-control" id="subTotalDiscount" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <label for="Tax" class="label-control">Tax : </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="number" name="Tax" value="" min="0" max="100" class="form-control" id="inputTax" onchange="calculatedSubTotal()"><span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="number" name="SubTotalTax" style="text-align: right;" class="form-control" id="subTotalTax" value="" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

i have try to look at people who ask the same question but i still need somekind a detail how the model.php, controller.php, view.php, script.js work, if you need more details here's the link the ui that i already made : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCAXK.png

Comment: you can use javascript to calculate the total or you want from query itself

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Comment: @HastaDhana sorry i didn't see yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the subtotal using CodeIgniter, but you have to use javascript to calculate the tax because it involves user interaction.

For example you have the subtotal input like this :

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="SubTotal">Sub Total</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="number" name="SubTotal" id="subTotal" class="form-control" value="" title="Sub Total" disabled><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="Discount">Discount</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                    <input type="number" name="Discount" id="inputDiscount" class="form-control" value="" title="Discount" min="0" max="100" onchange="calculateSubTotal()"><span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="number" name="SubTotalDiscount" id="subTotalDiscount" class="form-control" value="" title="Subtotal After Discount" disabled><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="Tax">Tax</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="input-group input-group-md">
                    <input type="number" name="Tax" id="inputTax" class="form-control" value="" title="Tax" min="0" max="100" onchange="calculateSubTotal()"><span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="number" name="SubTotalTax" id="subTotalTax" class="form-control" value="" title="Subtotal After Tax" disabled><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then you could set the subtotal value and also count the subtotals value after discount and after tax like this :

```
<script>
    jQuery(function () {
        let sum = 0.0;
        jQuery('.calc').each(function() {
            sum += parseInt(jQuery(this).text());
        });
        jQuery("#subTotal").val(sum);
    });
    function calculateSubTotal() {
        let subtotal = jQuery("#subTotal").val();
        jQuery("#subTotalDiscount").val(subtotal - (Math.round((jQuery("#inputDiscount").val() / 100) * subtotal)));
        let subtotal_discount = jQuery("#subTotalDiscount").val();
        jQuery("#subTotalTax").val(+subtotal_discount + (Math.round((jQuery("#inputTax").val() / 100) * subtotal_discount)));
    }
</script>
```

That will set all of the subtotals using javascript instead.

Comment: have you assign the `id="subTotal"` to the *Sub Total* input? also do you get any console message? also, could you share the subtotal, discount & tax input code?

Comment: yeah i did assign my subtotal id to that, yeah sure i just edited my question

Comment: I see you've renamed the `calculateSubTotal()` to `calculatedSubTotal()` on your code, could also you show the javascript code?

Comment: the javascript i try is the one that u write

Comment: there is no error, only there is no value that shows up

Comment: So the *Sub Total* (first input) value is empty?

Comment: yeah the ```subTotal``` input is empty

Comment: Try this on console : `let y = 0.0;$('.calc').each(function(){y += parseInt($(this).text())});console.log(y);`, what does it return?

Comment: can you explain to me how to do that, i still not really understand javascript

Comment: Open Dev Tools by pressing : `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`i` OR `F12`, then paste those codes on the *Console* tab

Comment: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null
at <anonymous>:1:23```

it return that error

Comment: please refresh the page and try replace `$` sign with `jQuery` on the console : `let y = 0.0;jQuery('.calc').each(function(){y += parseInt(jQuery(this).text())});console.log(y);`

Comment: yeah it show the sum value of subTotal from the table

Comment: if i use ```$(function () {
        let sum = 0.0;
        $('.calc').each(function() {
            sum += parseInt($(this).text());
        });
        $("#subTotal").val(sum);
    });``` 

in console it return this ```k.fn.init [document]``` and the value appear in the input box

Comment: its works! thank you, is it because i havent install jquery?

Comment: you're welcome! maybe it's because your library using `jQuery.noConflict()` which in order to use the jquery, you have to replace `$` with `jQuery`, [more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6746395/8566549)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select_sum('your_column_to_calculate');
$this->db->select('your_column_to_calculate');
$this->db->from('price');
$this->db->get();
```

or like this:

```
query = $this->db->query('SELECT sum(your_column_to_calculate) FROM price');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: can show me how to sum a join table? like the code that i just add

Answer (score 0):

This is javascript code,This calculate the only the calc row and show the result in subtotal  text box and it will load automatically:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){               

                    var hh2 = 0;              
                    $('#tebal > tbody  > tr').each(function() {
              var price = $(this).find('.calc').val();
                hh2 += parseFloat(price);                   
                    });
$('#SubTotal').val(hh2);
            });
</script>
```

Comment: if i input the value of tax ```10%``` and it will output the value of  ```subtotal*tax```

Comment: did you got it or not

Answer (score 0):

you can count all of the sum with php itself

> set variable $subtotal with zero, and add $subtotal in every loop

```
<?php 
$subtotal = 0;
foreach ($dataTabel as $kiki) : ?>
<tr class="table-row">
    ....
</tr> <?php $subtotal = $subtotal+$kiki["qty_op"]*$kiki["price"]; endforeach;?>
```

Hope you get it.